# After reboot files losts and old versions restored!? Ext4

Tags: boot, ext4, vmware

A linux  3.2.0-54-generic, Ubuntu 12.04 on Vmware was rebooted and then files disappeared and very old versions appeared on /etc.

It gave problems at booting, I copy part of dmesg

```
[   18.824677] EXT4-fs (sda3): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[   18.824775] EXT4-fs (sda3): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   18.880398] EXT4-fs (sda3): recovery complete
[   18.881200] EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   19.969324] init: ureadahead main process (935) terminated with status 5
[   20.214351] Adding 47184892k swap on /dev/sde1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:47184892k
[   21.141077] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   21.810513] EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   21.816038] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   21.816049] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[   21.816057] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[   21.844464] EXT4-fs (dm-0): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
[   21.846283] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[   21.863196] EXT4-fs (dm-1): warning: mounting unchecked fs, running e2fsck is recommended
[   21.863743] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
[   21.933761] EXT4-fs (sdf1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Files like `/etc/fstab` came with old configurations and the time stamp of many in `/etc` were old, changes of the last year have been lost, we have backup, no problem, and it's working now but we want to know what could have happened.

Either a vmware snapshot was restored somehow (none in the logs, none were active) or the ext4fs journal logs somehow failed and restored old versions.

A second eth2 disappeared from `/etc/network/interfaces`, `fstab` had a new wrong entry... `apache2` had only old files, etc...

What could have happened?

I rebooted the machine 2 times, it was stuck for 15 minutes at this prompt as shown in this image, I rebooted it again and then it booted with old files in `/etc`, (and `rw`).

[image: Rebooting, vmware, checking FS]

Answer (score 1):

Your filesystem had issues detected by fsck during the boot process. It tried to fix them and ended up pointing inodes to old data, restoring an old version of your ext4 metadata or your new data were never correctly written to disk.

Stop execution of your vm to avoid overwriting the data or create a disk snapshot that you can analyze with a file recovery tool. You can also seek professional data recovery services to get your files back, if they even still exist.